# Independence between sum of $F(X_i)$ and the cumulative distribution function $F$

Tags: nonparametric, independence

I am stuck in the following problem. $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random
sample from a continuous distribution with Cumulative Distribution
Function (CDF) $F$. Prove that the distribution of $T=\sum_{i=1}^m X_i$
is independent of $F$.

I tried as follows.

Due to the probability integral transformation, $F(X_i)\sim U(0,1)$.
Let $Y_i=F(X_i)$, then $Y_i\sim U(0,1)$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\log(y_i) & = & \operatorname{Exponential}(1)\\
 & \implies & y_i=e^{-\operatorname{Exponential}(1)}\\
 & \implies & T=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = \sum_{i=1}^n e^{-\operatorname{Exponential}(1)}\\
 & = & ne^{-\operatorname{Exponential}(1)}
\end{eqnarray*}

I have no idea how to argue this function of $\operatorname{Exponential}(1)$ is
independent of the CDF $F$.

Comment: Please format you question properly using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Title and body are slightly different. Sum of F(Xi) or sum of Xi?

Comment: Where you wrote "sum[(Xi), i=1,...n]", might you have meant "sum[F(Xi), i=1,...n]"? $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that where you wrote "sum[(Xi), i=1,...n]" you meant "sum[F(Xi), i=1,...n]", i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n F(X_i).$

For $0\le y\le1$ you have
\begin{align}
& \Pr(F(X_i)\le y) = \Pr(X_i\le\max\{x: F(x)\le y\}) \\[10pt]
= {} & F(\max\{x: F(x)\le y\}) = y. \tag 1
\end{align}
In other words, the c.d.f. of $F(X_i)$ is $y\mapsto y$ for $0\le y\le 1.$ That means $F(X_i)$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1],$ regardless of which function $F$ is.

The assumption that $F$ is continuous is used in line $(1),$ which assumes there actually is at least one point $x$ for which $F(x)=y.$ That is because continuous functions have the intermediate value property.

Comment: My apology. I will be more careful to format properly in the future. I am really new. Michael, you are right. I meant sum[F(Xi), i=1,....,n], not  sum[(Xi), i=1,...,n]. Thanks for correction. I like your idea. I could not hit that idea. Thanks a lot !!!